# Why stripe doesn't correctly redirect after payment with vue-stripe

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments

I try to use stripe in a Laravel vuejs SPA.
I first installed [vue-stripe](https://github.com/vue-stripe/vue-stripe#readme) with this command

```
npm i @vue-stripe/vue-stripe
```

Here is my component to trigger the payment

```html
<template>
  <div class="text-xl sass-editor-1 text-center">
    <h1 class="text-2xl">Stripe Payment Gateway integration</h1>
    <stripe-checkout
    ref="checkoutRef"
    mode="payment"
    :pk="publishableKey"
    :line-items="lineItems"
    :sucess-url="successURL"
    :cancel-url="cancelURL"
    @loading="v =>loading = v"
    />
    <button  class="mt-4 p-2 text-white border-2 border-white rounded-lg bg-green-800" @click="submit">Pay now</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import {ref } from 'vue'
  import {StripeCheckout} from '@vue-stripe/vue-stripe'
  let publishableKey = "pk_test_51M6ZtzIWDjpHNQK16d1g0bq1L6wHgFxNg9KyuBiThC4fSXgAyUVjlwG6MFos0AaqaQYJOf2YC3a6oWlZqMjFtTZj00Tue51qVs"
  let loading = ref(false);
  let lineItems = ref();
  lineItems.value = [
    {
      price: 'price_1M6qubIWDjpHNQ1rITHepQD',
      quantity: 1
    }
  ];

  let successURL = ref(null);
  successURL.value = 'http://localhost:3000/success';

  let cancelURL = ref(null);
  cancelURL.value = 'https://localhost:3000/error';
  const checkoutRef = ref(null);
  function submit() {
    //stripe checkout page
    checkoutRef.value.redirectToCheckout();
  }
</script>
```

I also created pages for success an error that display a short message.

When I click the button, I am redirected of the stripe page to enter my credential and my card number.
After confirming the payment, I am not redirected to the success nor the error page but to the page that initiated the process, i.e. the page I describe here.

How comes the redirection doesn't work ?

P.S. the original script has been converted to the "script setup" form, but even with the classic form, the trouble is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is mine works perfectly try to change from successURL.value to just successURL.

refer to this documentation https://docs.vuestripe.com/vue-stripe/stripe-checkout/subscriptions and look on this page exactly to the code they also use just successURL and cancelURL no value.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <stripe-checkout
      ref="checkoutRef"
      mode="subscription"
      :pk="publishableKey"
      :line-items="lineItems"
      :success-url="successURL"
      :cancel-url="cancelURL"
      @loading="v => loading = v"
    />
    <button @click="submit">Subscribe!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { StripeCheckout } from '@vue-stripe/vue-stripe';
export default {
  components: {
    StripeCheckout,
  },
  data () {
    return {
        el:"checkoutRef",
        publishableKey : import.meta.env.VITE_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
        loading: false,
        lineItems: [
            {
            price: 'price_1LgqdGALkwKTK48qE1lfox5G',
            quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
        successURL: 'https://'+window.location.host+'/success',
        cancelURL: 'https://'+window.location.host+'/cancel',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submit () {
      this.$refs.checkoutRef.redirectToCheckout();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```